# Lightning: Change search and lookup dialog box

Tags: lookup, search, search-layout

We are using the Account Hierarchy. Some accounts have 10-15 child accounts. The name of all these accounts is the same, the location (address) CAN be the same, but usually is not. When searching for these accounts they all display the same way. There are several fields which differentiate the accounts. I want to display those fields in the search and lookup dialog so the user knows which account to pick when in a lookup field or in the quick search.

I have tried to modify the mini-layouts, but this does not reflect in any changes in the UI. What should I do to accomplish this?

Adding additional information to the name field to differentiate them is a dirty solution and not really an option, because when sending them an Invoice they will return them because the company name is incorrect (Yes, this has happend in the past).

[image: screenshot]

How to proceed from here?

Comment: Any updates on this topic? I've got the exact same use case and I'm wondering what is the work around? Configure in Classic and run in Lightning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open Idea on Salesforce Community for that topic.  You can upvote:

[Allow user to choose any field to display in "instant results" in Global Search](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CTJ6QAO)

However, if you want to customize the **Lookup Search Results** (Second Line Information).  This is what I found.

IMPORTANT: You need to go through Classic to make those changes.

[image]

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pLvd

Answer (score 1):

I'm just investigating this. One year later on from your message.

So, it appears that Lookup Dialog is not available to be edited in Lightning:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_search.htm&type=5

I'm going to keep digging to see if there are any other developments.